# Python string formatting: get value in a dictionary by using index of another keyword

Tags: python, dictionary, string-formatting, keyword-argument

I am exploring what I can and cannot do with the `format()` method.

Say I am trying to format a string `"5/11/2013"` like `"11 May 2013"`.

This is what I have tried:

```
string = "5/11/2013"
dictionary = {"5": "May"}

print "{part[1]} {month[{part[0]}]} {part[2]}".format(
    part=string.split('/'), month=dictionary)
```

Which returns:

```
KeyError: '{part[0'
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to nest arguments like `{month[{part[0]}]}`?

Comment: Why not parse that into an actual `datetime` object and then use the `strftime()` method to format a proper date?

Comment: Well, yes, but this question is more about learning what is possible in string formatting than about getting a correct date. I am exploring the `format()` method, trying to understand what I can and can't do with it.

Comment: Although you can interpolate formatting parameters (width, etc.) you cannot do what you want; interpolate parameter indices. That's just a step too far.

Comment: I see. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22731089/2521769) would probably be the next best approach to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe in two steps:

```
>>> dictionary = {5: "May"}
>>> "{part[1]} {{month[{part[0]}]}} {part[2]}".format(part=string.split('/')).format(month=dictionary)
'11 May 2013'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try it as follows:

```
string = "5/11/2013".split('/')
dictionary = {"5": "May"}

print "{} {} {}".format(string[1],dictionary[string[0]],string[2])
```

It's also easier to understand than what you are doing there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731003/python-string-formatting-get-value-in-a-dictionary-by-using-index-of-another-ke#comment34643624_22731003

Comment: @thefourtheye, I saw that, that is why I stuck to string formatting.